# How to have by-reference locals in coroutines in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, iterator, pass-by-reference, coroutine

I have some functions that take in an Enemy instance and change one of its fields. The Enemy class has some basic fields like speed, damage, attack range. Each function just stores one of the normal value of the enemy and then change the current field to some value for an amount of time and then change it back to the normal state (I code in Unity and use Coroutine for this). The difference is which field to store (speed or damage or attack range, etc). So I want to make a single function that takes in a delegate that returns the field that it wants to change:

```
delegate ref float Stat();

private IEnumerator EnemyStatModify(Enemies enemy, float duration, float percent, Stat stat)
{
    ref float enemyStat = ref stat();
    float normalStat = enemyStat;
    enemyStat *= (1 - percent);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
    enemyStat = normalStat;
}
```

and then use it like this

`EnemyStatModify(enemy, state.duration, state.timeBtwHits, () => ref enemy.speed);`

`EnemyStatModify(enemy, state.duration, state.timeBtwHits, () => ref enemy.damage);`

But Iterators can't have by-reference locals. How to bypass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need the return value of your delegate. You also don't need the `Enemies` since you don't use it in the routine anyway.

This is of course still not as beautiful as `ref` parameters would be but you could simply use a callback like

```
delegate void Stat(float newValue);


private IEnumerator EnemyStatModify(float duration, float percent, float currentValue, Stat onUpdated)
//or
//private IEnumerator EnemyStatModify(float duration, float percent, float stat, Action<float> onUpdated)
{
    onUpdated?.Invoke(currentValue * (1 - percent));

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);

    onUpdated?.Invoke(currentValue);
}
```

and call it like

```
StartCoroutine(EnemyStatModify(state.duration, state.timeBtwHits, enemy.speed, (newValue) => 
{ 
    enemy.speed = newValue; 
}));

StartCoroutine(EnemyStatModify(state.duration, state.timeBtwHits, enemy.damage, (newValue) => 
{ 
    enemy.damage = newValue; 
});
```

Instead of the `Stat` you could also just use a `Action<float>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think this is way better than `ref` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround would be to give the coroutine getter and setter delegates. This would let you get the stat at any point, not just the beginning:

```
delegate float GetStat();
delegate void SetStat(float x);

private IEnumerator DelayedEnemyStatModify(Enemies enemy, float duration, float percent, GetStat getStat, SetStat setStat)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration/2f);
    float enemyStat = getStat();
    float normalStat = enemyStat;
    enemyStat *= (1 - percent);
    setStat(enemyStat);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration/2f);
    setStat(normalStat);
}
```

or in cases where you always/only get the stat at the start, just pass it by value:

```
delegate void SetStat(float x);

private IEnumerator EnemyStatModify(Enemies enemy, float duration, float percent, float enemyStat, SetStat setStat)
{
    float normalStat = enemyStat;
    enemyStat *= (1 - percent);
    setStat(enemyStat);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
    setStat(normalStat);
}
```