# Pass a boolean by reference in a Coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having an issue with passing in a boolean by reference inside a coroutine. I think that in order to achieve this I need to do it via a delegate but I don't have much experience with them and after a few hours trying to code this I feel a bit burnt out so I thought to give it a try and ask about it here. The code goes as follows:

```
private IEnumerator AnimationDelay(float delay, bool condition)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

    SwitchBool(ref condition);
}

private void SwitchBool(ref bool condition)
{
    condition = !condition;
}
```

I want to call that Coroutine with a delay and pass in the boolean I want to be switched, but Coroutines don't accept a ref parameter so the above logic doesn't work. I am trying to use this to stop my games animations via code and I want it to be flexible so I can just pass in a boolean controlling each animation and change it for each animation to stop playing.

I tried creating a delegate in the following form:

```
private delegate void Callback(ref bool switchBool);
private Callback del;

void Awake()
{
   del = new Callback(SwitchBool);
}
```

but I am not sure how to pass this delegate in the Coroutine and at the same time assign its boolean parameter.

If someone could help I would be grateful. I could go around this and just make separate Coroutines for each animation or even separate methods that I could invoke to switch each boolean for each animation, but this will get messy when I implement a lot of animations and I would like to try and make this clean way work!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have by-reference locals in coroutines in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64338379/how-to-have-by-reference-locals-in-coroutines-in-unity)

Comment: You could wrap that bool in a class, and pass an instance of that class to the coroutine.

Comment: @hijinxbassist it wouldn't really help though ;) I think the main purpose would be to directly affect an already existing bool field like as it would via `ref` .. putting it into an additional class is not really the same thing